# Prevent Subclassing Objective-C Classes in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, subclass

I'm adding Swift interior annotations to my Objective-C classes. I'm trying to prevent my class from being subclassed:

```
__attribute__((objc_subclassing_restricted))
@interface CWTestFinalClass : NSObject
@end
```

This works as expected in Objective-C:

```
// Generates Error, as expected
@interface CWTestSubclass : CWTestFinalClass
@end
```

However, I'm still able to subclass in Swift

```
// Should fail, but works without error
class TestSubclass: CWTestFinalClass {

}
```

**Question:** How do I prevent Objective-C classes from being subclassed in Swift?

Comment: I'm curious, why do you care what language people subclass your class in?

Comment: @Alexander - I don't care which language, but I need to ensure that it's not able to be subclassed in Swift or Objective-C. Currently, it cannot be subclassed in Objective-C. I want to duplicate this functionality in Swift.

Comment: Ah. That's not generally supported in Objective C, hence why there's no `final` keyword in the lagnuage. Even if there was, you could just dynamically create subclasses using the runtime APIs. The `objc_subclassing_restricted` attribute was added when Swift became a thing, specifically for enforcing that `final` Swift classes stay final in Objective C. But generally, Objective C's convention is to support subclassing on all classes. For one, there's no performance benefit to using `final`, because Objective C method calls are always dynamically dispatched. There's no de-virtualization.

Comment: @Alexander you should add that as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objective C does not have a `final` keyword, or anything like it. Even if a compile-time attribute or modifier did exist, it could trivially be sidelined by the use of the runtime APIs to dynamically create a subclass of any psuedofinal class.

The Swift compiler enforced that Swift could block attempts to subclass a `final` class, but that wouldn't stop Objective C from being able to do so (which isn't compiled through the Swift compiler). Thus, the `objc_subclassing_restricted` attribute was added, specifically to make clang enforce the illegality of subclassing `final` Swift classes.

There really isn't much of a benefit to making Objective C classes final, even if it were possible. Objective C is a much more dynamic language, that seems to follow Python's "we're all adults here" mantra.

The biggest reason to support `final` classes is inform the compiler which classes are candidates for de-virtualization. But Objective C always uses dynamic dispatch, and never does de-virtualization, anyway.

Comment: I'm confused; I thought you could not subclass Swift classes from Objective-C code...

Comment: @NicolasMiari Oh yeah. That's yet another reason why `objc_subclassing_restricted` would be necessary.